# How to add additional Woocommerce fields?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tell me how to pass additional fields to the cart (array) in Woocommerce, on the product page I create an array $discount_data:

```
<? $discount_data = array();
        
        $max_ticket_quantity = 0;
        foreach ( $buttons_rule as $predefined_button_id => $button_data ) :
            $ticket_quantity = $product->get_predefined_buttons_ticket_quantity( $predefined_button_id );
            $discount_amount = $product->get_predefined_buttons_discount_amount( $predefined_button_id );
            $discount_data[$ticket_quantity] = $discount_amount;
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>

    <input type='hidden' name="discount_data" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($discount_data)); ?>"/>
    
    <input type='hidden' class='lty-predefined-button-id' name='lty_predefined_button_id'/>
    <input type='hidden' class='lty-per-ticket-amount' name='lty_per_ticket_amount' value='<?php echo esc_attr( $per_ticket_amount ); ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' class='lty-ticket-quantity' name='quantity' value='1'/>
</div>
```

Using the function in function.php I want to get it and use it for my purposes, but I get NULL:

```
function woo_discount_total(WC_Cart $cart) {
    if(is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;    
    }

$discount_data = json_decode($_POST['discount_data']);

    var_dump($discount_data);

    $woo_count_item = $cart->get_cart_contents_count(); 

   
    if(isset($discount_data[$woo_count_item])) {
       
        $discount_percent = str_replace('%', '', $discount_data[$woo_count_item]);
       
        $discount = $cart->subtotal * ($discount_percent / 100);
        $cart->add_fee('Скидка: ', -$discount);
    }
}


add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_discount_total');
```

I have already tried to write it both in the session and in cookies, but I get null

I have already tried to write it both in the session and in cookies, but I get null